# How can I pass json variable to array of objects

Tags: json, typescript, oop

im currently working on this project and im facing this error when I try to pass a variable (this.arrayObj) into the composals array.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.apiService.getComposals().subscribe((res) => {
    console.log(res.tpoCampos);
    this.arrayObj = res.tpoCampos;
  });
}
```

Im getting the Json content from a Web Service.

```
export class AppComponent {

title = 'Form';
arrayObj: any;

composals: Composal[] = [
  this.arrayObj,
]; 
}
```

This is the content from the webservice

```
{  
 "m_iPatientID":2,
 "tpoCampos":[  
  {  
     "m_cColor":"#000000",
     "m_cType":"combo",
     "m_cOptions":[  
        "Sim",
        "N\u00e3o"
     ],
     "m_cQuestion":"",
     "m_cAnswer":"2",
     "m_eIdComposant":4443
  },
  {  
     "m_cColor":"#000000",
     "m_cType":"combo",
     "m_cOptions":[  
        "Sim",
        "N\u00e3o"
     ],
     "m_cQuestion":"",
     "m_cAnswer":"2",
     "m_eIdComposant":4448
  }
 ]
}
```

How can I pass the json to the composal object inside the variable this.arrayObj?

Comment: where you are getting a problem ?

Comment: composals: Composal[] = [
  this.arrayObj,                                   -> Here
];

Comment: try like this composals: Composal[] = this.arrayObj;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `this.arrayObj` is already an array of objects, so it could be written like this

`composals: Composal[] = this.arrayObj;`

```
 export class AppComponent {

    title = 'Form';
    arrayObj: any;

    composals: Composal[] = this.arrayObj; 
 }
```

Comment: Nothing was displayed. But when I console.log(this.arrayObj) the json is printed, so I  dont know why ist anything displayed

Comment: Is it possible that the error comes from the "[" after the "tpoCampos" in the json? ("tpoCampos":[  
  {  )

Comment: No, your json structure is fine, Can you please share what error you are getting?

Comment: im not getting any error, nothing is being displayed

Comment: Are you iterating this.arrayObj or composals  in the template ? you need to iterate this.arrayObj. because that’s where we are setting the value in ngOnInit

Comment: Genius! Thank you very much.